# How to "look deep into one's eyes"?

Tags: greek, idiom

In [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/to-aid-love-lost-and-gained), the idiom "to look deep into one's eyes" came up. While the rest of the translation was relatively straightforward, I don't know of any equivalent idiom in Greek or Latin.

If I wanted to say "when I look deep into your eyes", for example, how would I go about it?

Comment: perhaps something like *cum oculos imos video*

Answer (score 2):

I hope there are better ideas than mine, but let me record it here anyway.
As I mentioned in the linked question, I have used this Latin translation:

> *Quando oculos eius profundos specto/video/aspicio…*

As [Anonym](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/427/anonym) comments under the question, *imos* is one option to replace *profundos*.

Answer (score 2):

In the Ars Amatorio, it mentions this, but just has *oculos... spectare*. Pretty boring.

To look deeply into something is *inspicio*, but this might be too clinical. Nevertheless, it could work.

However, maybe the best option is suggested by the following passage from the first Phillipic of Cicero:

**Sed per deos immortalis!—te enim intuens, Dolabella, qui es mihi carissimus,...** 
 (By the immortal gods!--when I look at you, Dolabella, as much as you are most dear to me...)

So, we see this word *intueor* which suits our purpose nicely:

***Cum in oculos tuos alte intueor...***

This has just the right romantic and intimate tone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the Greek came up, but

- ἐμβλέπω τινὶ τοῖς ὀφθαλμοῖς

might come [close](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%90%CE%BC%CE%B2%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%80%CF%89), So,

- Βαθέως ἐμβλέπων σοῦ τοὺς ὀφθαλμούς... ?

Comment: Why dative instead of εἰς + acc., as in the Plato example? I'm tempted to read your proposal as "looking at you deeply *with my eyes*."

Comment: βλέπω ἐν τοῖς ὀφθαμοῖς : The active preposition is the  ἐν attaching to the verb.

Comment: I don't think verb prefixes generally work like that (e.g. in many cases, at least in Ancient Greek, the preposition is repeated) but I see now that the L&S entry you linked does list the dative usage with the same meaning, so this works! But I'd definitely recommend using an example that has the same construction as your proposed translation, so that the parallel is clearer!

Comment: I think you are right. I misread the instrumental in Charmides, Pl,  and, indeed, my reading of the entry was fanciful... Thanks.